# Big WAMP issue with orange icon

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I have a problem with WAMP becouse that dont want to start, icon stay orange all the time.

What I try:

1. I change Skype port to :88 (dont work)
2. I change port on httpd.conf:

> Listen 12.34.56.78:8080listen 0.0.0.0:8080 Listen [::0]:
>
> 8080

Dont Work

3. I run at CMD: iisreset /stop and then try to run WAMP (dont work)

WHen I run Test port 80 I get message: Your port is not actually used.

I really dont know what is a problem here! Please help!
My apache error log say:

```
[Sat Dec 05 14:23:40.045710 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1936:tid 396] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Dec 05 14:23:40.061311 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1936:tid 396] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:13:13
[Sat Dec 05 14:23:40.061311 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1936:tid 396] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Sat Dec 05 14:23:40.061311 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1936:tid 396] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2748
[Sat Dec 05 14:23:40.716512 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2748:tid 328] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sat Dec 05 23:24:18.242493 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1936:tid 396] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sat Dec 05 23:24:20.270497 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2748:tid 328] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Sat Dec 05 23:24:20.395297 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1936:tid 396] AH00430: Parent: Child process 2748 exited successfully.
```

Comment: YESTREDAY EVERYTHING WAS FINE!!!

Comment: When I try to go at: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ I get: This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not Apache that is the issue.

You probably have a database corruption.

Look at your mysql error log using the wampmanager menus like this

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> MySQL Log
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first.

Close WAMP and try **netstat -a** or use [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html).

Check which process is using the same port that WAMP uses, 80? 443?

Kill the process with **taskkill /T /F /IM name_of_process.exe**

Try to run WAMP again.

Repeat the process and make sure that Apache is on port 80/443.

Comment: I change partition to C: but now WAMP is green, but I cant run php -V command

Comment: Check the PATH variable